# Query returning Union of two tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to retrieve data from a table using multi-column subquery but it unions the result from both tables. I'm unable to modify it to get actual results.
Here is my query

```
select * 
from   Recipe, user_plan 
where  Recipe.id in (select meal_number 
                     from user_plan 
                      where week_id=(select max(week_id) 
                                     from user_plan 
                                     where user_id=:user_id))
```

**Recipe Structure**

[image]

---

**user_plan structure**
[image]
It should return 2 rows as per my expectations and data available in tables but it is returning 10 rows.Please help me figure this out. Thanks.
I'm using mysql-server on ubuntu

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Use `JOIN` instead if `IN ( SELECT ... )`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing user id condition in the outer query.

```
select 
* FROM 
user_plan inner join receipe
on a.receipe_id = b.id
where a.user_id =:user_id and b.week_id  
= ( SELECT max(week_id) FROM user_plan where user_id=:user_id)
```